# Why can't I bold text by clicking a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone explain why clicking a button will trigger a browser edit  in a contentEditable div but clicking a div that calls the same execCommand does not?  In http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/3/ I have a button and a div that trigger the same code but only the button executes the bold action:

```
<div id="boldB">B</div>
<button id="bld">B</button>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#boldB').click(function() {
            document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
            alert("clicked the B div");
        });

    $('#bld').click(function() {
            document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
            alert("clicked the B button");
        });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like a focus issue. You'll notice when you click the div, the highlighted text in the contenteditable loses focus, whereas it doesn't on the button click. You perhaps need to store the highlighted range on blur if using a div as a button first. May I ask why you need to use a div when you could easily style the button how you want?

Comment: did you need this ? http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/4/

Comment: did you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/8/

Comment: Wow... looks like nobody actually tries out provided example. All 'solutions' so far are off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click on a `div`, the currently selected `div` loses focus, so there is nothing for the `execCommand` function to do. You need to catch the event earlier (e.g. on mouse down), and prevent it. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/13/

Line by line explanation:

```
$('#boldB').mousedown(function(e) {
```

The mousedown event is called before the click event, and before the focus changes, giving us the opportunity to prevent it from changing.

```
    e.preventDefault();
```

calling `preventDefault` on the event object will prevent the subsequent default actions from occuring, i.e. change of focus.

```
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

Having done that, you can safely `execCommand` on your `div`, since it is still in focus and the selection is intact.

Comment: I don't know who or why you got downvoted but this is correct.

Comment: JSFiddle didn't save my code edits the first time, so the example didn't work. Lucky I noticed quickly.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it.  Is there a way to see what selection is being passed to the browser, so I would have seen null in  this case?

Comment: @Steve you could check if the text box `div` is in focus instead, since even if there is no selection but it is in focus, the text that is typed in at the current insertion point will become bold: http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/15/
This checks if the text box is in focus, and doesn't execute the command if it isn't.

Answer (score -4):

Here, try this http://jsfiddle.net/GgX8G/7/

the line of jquery you want is this:

```
$("#boldB").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: How does this allow you to highlight a specific word in the contenteditable area without highlighting all the text?

Comment: The goal isn't to bold some text.  The goal is to get contenteditable to work.  I just used bold as a simple example of what wasn't working.